# In PHP, is declaring its variable type optional when passing a reference to a function?

Tags: php, function, parameters

im new to PHP and i have come across two ways that people declare their functions parameters.

```
function fun(array &$array)
{
   return $stuff
}
```

OR

```
function fun($array)
{
   return $stuff
}
```

From what i read in the documentation the `&` passes the reference to the variable. but i thought that declaring the type `array` was unnecessary.

So, when i pass reference to a variable in a function is declaring its variable type optional?

Meaning is `function fun(array &$array)` AND `function fun(&$array)` equivalent/allowed?

Comment: Declaring type `array` in a function call definition is called [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php): PHP will issue a catchable fatal error if the argument passed to `fun()` isn't an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, Its optional because not all values are allowed. You can specify non scalar values (arrays, objects etc) but not ints strings floats etc

Your last line they are the same, with the exception that a catchable fatal error is thrown if its called like this

```
fun("1")
fun(false)
```

the way without the type hint would allow the function to be run and the functions logic would have to test that its argument is correct

Comment: So adding the "type hinting" (as Mark Baker pointed out the name) just adds some catchable fatal error to be thrown under certain conditions?

TY

Answer (score 0):

Simply you declare your funcion as "no referenced parameters", without "&". In the moment you call the function pass the variable as reference.

```
function fun(&$array)
{
     //function body

}
 fun($girlfriend_array);
```

You can use settype: http://php.net//manual/es/function.settype.php  for ensure a variable is type you want.

edited: change "&"  location.

Comment: Is it better than reassignate all the array? I like this way because if I need to modify only certain elements is quickly than read/write each array entry. There is another elegant solution instead? Prestashop 1.6 has references as this and no crashing in PHP 5.5